# Notation for equivalent items in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, equals, equivalent

I have two lists

```
circles_plotted = [1]
circles_next_plotted = [1]
```

Numbers are appended to list `circles_plotted` each time a circle is plotted. However, is the correct notation for and item in each of the lists to be equivalent? (this will be in an if statement):

```
(item in circles_next_plotted)==(item in circles_plotted)
```

Comment: Just do `circles_plotted == circles_next_plotted`, Python will internally takes care of the shallow comparisons.

Comment: @thefourtheye Will this still work when multiple values are in `circles_plotted` so not all the values inside the list are equivalent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The notation is incorrect.

```
(item in circles_next_plotted)==(item in circles_plotted)
```

is a `NameError` in Python:`name 'item' is not defined`.

What you **probably** meant is

```
>>> (item for item in circles_next_plotted)==(item for item in circles_plotted)
False
```

This is because `(item for item in circles_next_plotted)` is a generator expression and the two generators are two distinct objects, thus not equal.

```
>>> (item for item in circles_next_plotted)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000D50AF46BF8>
>>> (item for item in circles_plotted)    
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000D50AF46CA8>
```

To compare the lists you should use a simple comparison with the `==` operator which has been implemented for lists to do a per item comparison rather than a object identity check:

```
>>> circles_next_plotted==circles_plotted
True
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if lists are equal you can use `==`. If position of elements differ you can check if sorted lists are equal:

```
li1 = [1, 2, 3]
li2 = [1, 2, 3]

print(li1 == li2)  # True

li3 = [3, 2, 1]
li4 = [1, 2, 3]

print(li3 == li4)  # False
print(sorted(li3) == sorted(li4))  # True
```

Also you can check whether the multisets with the elements of li3 and li4 are equal:

```
import collections

li3 = [3, 2, 1]
li4 = [1, 2, 3]

print(collections.Counter(li3) == collections.Counter(li4))  # True
```